# Using sum and where

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to calculate the sum of all the purchases made by an customer.

I have a table with all the purchases (CustomerID, ItemID,Amount), a table for customer(CustomerID, Name,Address) and Item (ID, price).

This is my current best try but I get an error for how I use group by (which is weird in and of it self).

```
    SELECT name,address 
    FROM (purchases as p join customer as c on p.customerID = c.customerID
    join item as i on p.ean = i.ean)
    where sum(i.outprice * p.amount) >2500
    group by p.customerID;
```

This query below works perfectly. But all I'm trying to do is to only show where
sum(i.outprice * p.amount) > X for any given X.

```
    SELECT name,address,sum(i.outprice * p.amount)
    FROM (purchases as p join customer as c on p.customerID = c.customerID
    join item as i on p.ean = i.ean)
    group by p.customerID;
```

How should I go about doing this?

Thanks!

Comment: The general GROUP BY rule says:
If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT name,address 
    FROM (purchases as p join customer as c on p.customerID = c.customerID
    join item as i on p.ean = i.ean)
    group by p.customerID
having sum(i.outprice * p.amount) >2500
```

Comment: Thank you!! Works like a charm.

Comment: Adding to jarlh's comment above, even though MySQL allows this query to run the correct way is to say `min(address)` in the `select` list.